# How to test net.tcp service detailed below?

Tags: web-services, wcf, tcp, wcf-data-services

I want to test the below URL type, can you help me how to test it? what tool I need to use to see its actual request and response.

net.tcp://xxx.yyy.com:808/prod/zzzwebservice

I have also tried Wireshark and smart sniff but I can't see the request and response in detail in human readable form.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options. First one: `NetTcpBinding` uses transport layer encryption by default. Therefore you need to disable it if you want to inspect the message on Wireshark.

```
<netTcpBinding>
   <binding name="yourBindingConfiguration">
      <security mode="None" />
   </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

Or you can use WCF Tracing to check request & response.

- Right click your web.config/app.config and click Edit WCF Configuration
- Under Diagnostics section, enable Log Auto Flush, MessageLogging and Tracing and of course specify a path which your host identity has access to write.
- Check the trace file after you execute that service call. Then you can see the messages.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful.